# Fix Deprecated Function errors when installing inoERP in php version 7.2.4

Tags: php, deprecated

I have php version 7.2 installed on my PC and get a `deprecated function` error, whereas in php versions lower than 7.2 it is running normally.

```
function getQueriesFromSQLFile($sqlfile) {
 if (is_readable($sqlfile) === false) {
  throw new Exception($sqlfile . 'does not exist or is not readable.');
 }

 # read file into array
 $file = file($sqlfile);

 # import file line by line
 # and filter (remove) those lines, beginning with an sql comment token
 $file = array_filter($file, create_function('$line', 'return                 strpos(ltrim($line), "--") !== 0;'));

 # and filter (remove) those lines, beginning with an sql notes token
 $file = array_filter($file, create_function('$line', 'return     strpos(ltrim($line), "/*") !== 0;'));

 # this is a whitelist of SQL commands, which are allowed to follow a     semicolon
 $keywords = array(
  'ALTER', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'DROP', 'INSERT',
  'REPLACE', 'SELECT', 'SET', 'TRUNCATE', 'UPDATE', 'USE'
 );

 # create the regular expression for matching the whitelisted keywords
 $regexp = sprintf('/\s*;\s*(?=(%s)\b)/s', implode('|', $keywords));

 # split there
 $splitter = preg_split($regexp, implode("\r\n", $file));

 # remove trailing semicolon or whitespaces
 $splitter = array_map(create_function('$line', 'return     preg_replace("/[\s;]*$/", "", $line);'), $splitter);

 # remove empty lines
 return array_filter($splitter, create_function('$line', 'return     !empty($line);'));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create_function()` function [has been deprecated in 7.2](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php) as you noticed. It is a function you should strive not to use, it has been deprecated for reasons of security I believe, it wraps the very dangerous eval function. That function allows an attacker to execute arbitrary code on your machine under certain circumstances.

You should rather use anonymous functions such as

```
$file = array_filter(
    $file,
    function($line) { return strpos(ltrim($line), "--") !== 0; }
);
```